# Set UIDatePicker minimumDate to x days from now, e.g 2 days from today

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

How can I set the `minimumDate` of the `UIDatePicker` to 'x' number of days away? For example, set the `minimumDate` to be two days from todays date.

I can set the minimumDate to today using;

```
 UIDatePicker * datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 163)];
 datePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];
```

But I am unsure how to make it a day in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
 NSTimeInterval secondsPerHour = 3600;
 NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = secondsPerHour * 24;
 UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 163)];
 datePicker.minimumDate= [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2*secondsPerDay];
```

The method that you are looking for is `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` from `NSDate`, in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval%3a) you can find more info on it :)

Note that `NSTimeInterval` is always specified in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSDate` with the date that is two days from the current date:

```
NSTimeInterval oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
NSDate *twoDaysFromNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:oneDay * 2];
```